# How to get selected Text Value in choosen.js dropdown list

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a problem in my dropdown list using choosen.js.

I have this list in **MaterialName** dropdown list :
    MaterialName //id ="drpMaterial"

```
MaterialName1  //id="1" Text="MaterialName1"
MaterialName2  //id="2" Text="MaterialName2"
MaterialName3  //id="3" Text="MaterialName2"
```

Here's my logic:

Everytime I choose a MaterialName I get the **id** and put in the another textfield with the **StockNo** and I want the **text** to be added in my **datatable.**

The problem now is every time I get the **$("#drpMaterial").text()** I get the three(3) list which are the:

```
MaterialName1 
MaterialName2  
MaterialName3
```

All I want to get is the one I choose.

Here's my code, I just want to **alert** the **text** that I choose in Material dropdown list for now:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
                allow_single_deselect: true,
                display_selected_options: false,
                single_backstroke_delete: false,
                search_contains: true
            });
$("#drpMaterial").change(function () {
                alert($("#drpMaterial").text());
                $("#StockNo").val($("#drpMaterial").val());
            });
```

Please help... thanks.

Comment: use `$("#drpMaterial option:selected").text()`

Comment: i will put it as answer for other people reference

Comment: Okay, that would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#drpMaterial option:selected").text()
```

> Description: Selects all elements that are selected.

Use `option:selected` to select the text of selected option

Comment: this doesn't work with multiple-selected dropdown, only the last selected option.
The following code will work with multiple selected options

Comment: var options = $("#some_id  option:selected");

var values = $.map(options, function (option) {
    return option.text;
});